# Deploy laravel to InfinityFree

Tags: mysql, laravel

I am having problems uploading a **laravel** application to the infinityfree server, uploaded all my project files and connected the .env to db access, however when I run the url it displays me the message "Whoops, looks like something went wrong." and with the error "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)" on the console. As shown in the image the .env is configured like this:

```
DB_CONNECTION = mysql
DB_HOST = sql302.epizy.com
DB_DATABASE = epiz_21876899_db_luck
DB_USERNAME = epiz_21876899
DB_PASSWORD = bank password
```

My files are inside the htdocs folder that is at the root of the domain.

How to solve this problem?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/KNJPZ.png

Comment: Contact your hosting provider https://forum.infinityfree.net/discussion/1732/can-i-connect-externally-to-mysql-databases

Answer (score 0):

When you finish your configuration in the .env

Normally, you should change the document root of your website to the public folder with Laravel. You can’t do this on free hosting, but you can simulate this with .htaccess rules. These are the the .htaccess rules I used:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule (.*) /public/$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

- I usually configure by in .env file and config file ->database.php
- [Link aticle](https://shopttt.42web.io/config_and_deploy_laravel_hosting.php)
- [image config laravel in .env](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RUhd9.png)